# what is the meaning of the Michael words when he saw stunning girl dancing?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Michael & Matt watching nice girl dancing in a bar:

> Michael: If I come up with the scoop on her, I get Dallas at three and a
>   half.
>
> Matt: If you come up with anything on her, I'll give you six.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Werff about the meaning of *scoop*. I first heard it as in a news reporter getting the scoop on a situation. I had a friend who wanted to be a reporter who wanted to be called by the nickname Scoop. It just means information about something or someone, usually, the first information known.

But to answer the question as to the meaning of the numbers given, 3 1/2 and 6. These refer to "points": Giving someone a team plus points in sports betting is referred to as a point spread.

“An example of a point spread would be Green Bay Packers -7 Detroit Lions. This says that Green Bay is likely to win by a touchdown over Detroit. Someone betting on the game would have to pick one of the teams. If they selected Green Bay, then the team would have to win by more than seven points for the bet to be successful. If they bet on Detroit, then Detroit would either have to win or lose by six or less for the bet to be successful. A team can lose a game but beat the spread. For instance, in this example, a three point loss by Detroit would be considered to be "beating the spread". While most often used in gambling, it's also a way to show the competitiveness of a game."

https://www.sportingcharts.com/dictionary/nfl/point-spread.aspx

So, in this example, Michael says that if he gets the lowdown or the 411 (other slang expressions with the same approximate meaning) on the girl Matt should give him Dallas at 3½ (points). Michael obviously thinks this is a very good bet. Matt replies that if Michael gets anything at all, Matt will give him 6 (points), which is even better for Michael, but it also implies that Matt thinks it is unlikely that Michael will succeed.

Also in this example, to *come up with*, means to have a result at the end of an attempt. For example, "What did you come up with?" means "What were your results after your efforts to do something."

Answer (score 4):

In context, I would say that **the scoop** in this case refers to **information**.

**Scoop** is one of those words with a LOT of uses. Dictionary.com puts this at #10:

> **scoop**
>
> 10.
>   *Informal*. news, information, or details, especially as obtained from experience or an immediate source:
>   *What's the scoop on working this machine?*
>   [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scoop)

The key point is Matt's line "If you come up with **anything on her**", indicating that they're referring to information about the girl.

**Come up with** means to produce or acquire, especially in a pressure situation or when something is difficult to get.

My interpretation, then, would be that Michael is acting as Matt's **[wingman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingman_(social))**, approaching a girl Michael likes to get information about her - is she with a boyfriend, what's her name, is she with friends, etc.

I'm afraid I'm all at sea regarding the second part - sports are all Greek to me.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: @Werrf's answer referring to a "wingman" scenario is probably the right one here.

"Come up with the scoop" seems to be a blend of constructions.

To **scoop something up** means to grab it for yourself.  *I saw the bicycle on the curb with a sign that said "Free" so I scooped it up*.

To **come up with** means to end up having or holding something, usually in a melee in a sporting or competitive context.

*When the quarterback dropped the ball, three players went for it simultaneously.  The left tackle came up with the ball.*

*The paleontologist, the boy who had been missing, and his divorced parents all plunged their hands into the large piles of steaming dinosaur dung, searching for the ringing satellite phone. It was the paleontologist who came up with it.*

So it seems the meaning is, if I succeed in getting this girl, you have to give me a 3.5 point advantage when we're betting on the game.

The girl is being implicitly compared to a loose (American) football, and the guys in the bar as players competing with each other to scoop her up.

Comment: please give another example on **come up with**, I don't know how to compare with quaterback means,

Comment: I've added another example.

Comment: I believe @Werrf's interpretation of *the scoop* to be correct over yours here.

Comment: The wingman scenario is certainly plausible, and "scoop" can be a synonym for "info" aka "the skinny". I've given @Werrf's answer an upvote, but the site won't allow me to downvote my own answer.